# using php to save remote images files at local sever but not completely successfully

Tags: php

I know some people already ask it but my probelm is when downloading remote images files(each file size is smaller than 200KB). But some files won't be completly saved. And some files can not be saved, or some files are saved but not 100%, I will see some gray shadow at image. The worst is everytime is different error ouput.(it's internet problem?)

I try the following methods to save file.

1. file_get_contents
2. curl/GD
3. copy

it all can work but I can't find the perfect method to save whole files.

The followings are error msg.

1. failed to open stream: HTTP request
   failed! HTTP/1.0 408 Request
   Time-out in at line "copy"
2. Maximum
       execution time of 60 seconds
       exceeded( I increase time)

my php program.

```
set_time_limit(60);

$imageArray=array(image array............);

for ($k=0;$k<count($imageArray);$k++){

echo '<img src="'.$imageArray[$k].'"><br/>';

$isok=copy($imageArray[$k] , dirname(__FILE__).'/photo/item_'.($k+1).'.jpg');

if(isok==true){
   echo' success!';  
}else{
  echo ' Fail';  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most possibly it's an internet problem. Do they load fine in the browser when you try ? If they do, you can try running the code on your machine and see if this would help.

But most probable reason is the remote site which you try to download from - it can throttle you for connections per time-interval. Try sleeping between images - for example 5-6 seconds and see if this helps.

Also try to download smaller batches of images - 1 - 2 at a time to see if it works.

Comment: actually I only put 10 images source at this program. but anyway it's not my program bug...wish I can make internet speed quickly.

Comment: Best way to speed your connection is may be talk with your provider or change it. Or do it on a free shared hosting somewhere which allows remote http wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your copy() that you have hardcoded in .jpg to the destination output. Are you always uploading .jpg as if you are uploading a .png or .gif and are forcing it to .jpg you might be causing issues there. Just a thought to be honest.

Comment: It wouldn't matter. The browser handles these cases fine (at least FF, Chrome) and you can even put an img without extension on a page like: img src="http://example.com/thisshouldbeajpegimagewithoutext" and it will show just fine.

Comment: thanks...all files are jpg extension. same program running at my home can work very well...I think it's internet connection problem at my office.